# Proper jQuery selector for html elements with array name

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I have multiple check boxes in my code

```
<label>
 <input name="meta[Radio & Speakers]" class="flat" type="checkbox" value="YES"> Radio & Speakers
</label>
```

Whenever the checkboxes are unchecked, a hidden input is put before the unchecked checkbox with the same name using:

```
$('input').on('ifUnchecked', function(event){
    name = $(this).attr('name');

    if($('input[type="checkbox"][name="'+name+']"').length == 0){
        $(this).before('<input type="hidden" name="'+name+'" value="NO"/>');
    }

});
```

I would like to avoid multiple insertions of the hidden input by checking if it exists using `$('input[type="checkbox"][name="'+name+']"').length` but it seems to fail, There's something I'm missing out here ...

Manually adding hidden check boxes is not feasible for my scenario since they are so many.

Comment: What is `ifUnchecked` event?

Comment: `$("name='meta\[Radio \& Speakers\]'")`

Comment: @dfsq https://github.com/fronteed/icheck plugin

Comment: I think he is using `iCheck` plugin

Comment: @dfsq: I'm using the iCheck plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do it like below:-

1.use `click` event.(*if using plugin then go with your initial event `ifUnchecked`*)

2.check that checkbox is checked or unchecked.

3.If checkbox is unchecked then check that already hidden input is there are not.If not then only add hidden input.

Check the below snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input').on('click', function(event){ //or use $('input').on('ifUnchecked', function(event){
    name = $(this).attr('name');
    if(!$(this).is(":checked")){
     if($(this).parent('label').find('input[type="hidden"]').length ==0){
        $(this).before('<input type="hidden" name="'+name+'" value="NO"/>');
     }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input name="meta[Radio & Speakers]" class="flat" type="checkbox" value="YES"> Radio & Speakers</label>
```

Comment: Perfect! Solved it `if($(this).parent('div').find('input[type="hidden"]').length ==0){
                $(this).before('<input type="hidden" name="'+name+'" value="NO"/>');`
            }